# Call method of unknown subclass

Tags: java, reflection

I have abstract class in Java. I want to call to specific method of his subclass (if it exists) with reflection.

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public void doIt(String functionName) {
        if (the caller class have method called as functionName parameter) {
            call it
        }
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public void spacialMethod() {
        System.out.println("Child special method called");
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent{
    // Empty
}
```

So if I will run that code:

```
Child child = new Child();
child.doIt("spacialMethod"); // Will print the text
Child2 child2 = new Child2();
child2.doIt("spacialMethod"); // Nothing will happened
```

How can I check in the parent class if the current subclass have method called "specialMethod"?

Comment: Why? Why not just define a "do nothing" version in the abstract class, and call it, and if the subclass overrides it their version will get called?

Answer (score 5):

It's *possible* to do what you've asked (see the end of the answer), but it's poor design if done without good reason.

If you don't need to determine the name at runtime, I'd define the method in `Parent` as doing nothing, and then just call it; if the subclass overrides it, great.

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public void doIt() {
        this.specialMethod();
    }
    public void spacialMethod() {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    @Override
    public void spacialMethod() {
        // Optionally call super.specialMethod() here
        System.out.println("Child special method called");
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent{
    // Empty
}
```

But if you **really** want to do it with reflection (e.g., you need to define the name at runtime), it's not hard:

```
// Not recommended if you can avoid it
public void doIt() {
    try {
        this.getClass().getMethod("specialMethod").invoke(this);
    }
    catch (/*...appropriate exception handling...*/) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to create "default" `spacialMethod` in the parent, because I don't really know what is the method name, I can only find it at run time... Dose `this.getClass().getMethod("specialMethod")` will work if I don't declare it in the `Parent` class?

Comment: @nrofis then you've got a poor design.

Comment: @nrofis: Yes. That's an alternative, not an extension of the previous code block. `this.getClass()` gets the instance's class, which (in a subclass) is the subclass.

Comment: @AndyTurner I am trying to implement dynamic object with complex getter setter mechanism. For example if the child class has `setFoo` method so I will able to call to `set` of the parent class with the value, and it will automatically call to `setFoo` and set my value there... I took the idea from some framework (for other programming language)

Comment: Reflection has its place. It is heavily used in some sorts of frameworks and application servers. However, in other programs ("normal" applications) it usually is not a good option to use. Often, the same can be achieved with common, type safe programming.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answer from TJ Crowder you can use `getDeclaredMethods` to get all methods and invoke the *special* one.

```
 public void doIt() {
        Method[] methods = getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method method : methods){
          if(method.getName().contains("special"){
             method.invoke(this);
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just to remember that `getDeclaredMethods` does not return inherited methods, that is, the methods declared in the superclasses will not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example without reflection:

Have some kind of "accessor" which is implemented specifically for each child class, or not implemented; when implemented, it delegates to the desired method of the child.

Note that, unlike in the example below, the accessor implementations can be external to the classes themselves, so that the child does not even have to know that/how it will be accessed.

```
public interface SpecialOpAccessor {
  void doIt();
}

public abstract class Parent {
    protected SpecialOpAccessor accessor;

    public void doIt() {
       if ( accessor != null ) {
         accessor.doIt();
       }
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{

    public Child() {
      super();
      this.accessor = new SpecialOpAccessor() {
         @Override
         public void doIt() {
           Child.this.spacialMethod();
         }
      }
    }

    public void spacialMethod() {
        System.out.println("Child special method called");
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent{
    public Child() {
      super();
      this.accessor = null;
    }
}
```